# 'AADSTS500011' error message returned from API call using adalFetch

Tags: reactjs, rest, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a React application that is registered in Azure Active Directory. In the API Permissions section, I have added permissions to access the API I am trying to access.

I am using the react-adal package to handle login and storage of access tokens when the user enters the app. My understanding is that the access token for the API is created at this point and adalFetch handles the logistics during the call to the API.

The response from the API is an error object (I replaced the actual id's; yes they match exactly and are correct in AAD):

```
{
message: "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://<domain>.onmicrosoft.com/APP_ID/access_as_user was not found in the tenant named TENANT. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant."
msg: "invalid_resource"
}
```

I have searched high and low to find a solution to why this isn't working. There is documentation on the API, but none specifying a resource or anything beyond the various endpoints i.e. http://thing-api.azurewebsites.net/api/endpointGoesHere

The API page states:

To use the API, apps need to implement modern authentication (OIDC) using AzureAD (AAD) and then request a token from AAD for the API.

The app id in Azure is https://domain.onmicrosoft.com/APP_ID and requires the “access_as_user” scope.

**adalConfig.js**

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  tenant: TENANT,
  endpoints: {
    thingApi: 'https://<domain>.onmicrosoft.com/APP_ID/access_as_user',
    graphApi: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
  },
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
  adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.thingApi, fetch, url, options);

export const adalGraphFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
  adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.graphApi, fetch, url, options);
```

Function for the API call. Executed in componentDidMount.

**TrainLanding.jsx**

```
//Returns error
fetchData = () => {
    adalApiFetch(fetch, 'http://thing-api.azurewebsites.net/api/EventGet', {})
      .then((response) => {
        response.json()
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ apiResponse: JSON.stringify(responseJson, null, 2) }, () => {
              console.log(this.state.apiResponse)
            })
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }

//works perfectly fine
fetchGraph = () => {
    adalGraphFetch(fetch, 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {})
      .then((response) => {
        response.json()
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ apiResponse: JSON.stringify(responseJson, null, 2) }, () => {
              console.log(this.state.apiResponse)
            })
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }
```

I set up a graph API call in the exact same way to test the method, and it works perfectly fine. So I know adal is set up correctly, I just don't understand the error and where I am going wrong. My googling has not yielded any useful results.

Comment: I think you are mixing v1 (adal) with v2 (MSAL). ADAL doesn't use scopes, it uses resource identifiers only. So in your case either the API client id or the app ID URI.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip. I wasn't aware that ADAL was incapable of using scopes. I will look into using the react-aad-msal package I found instead!

Comment: @robertb.webdev If your issue has been resolved, you can add your solution as the answer. If you have any other concerns regarding this, just update your question.

Comment: I got this error
{message: "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https:/…959-c767cc4c040b
↵Timestamp: 2019-06-10 12:18:02Z", msg: "invalid_resource"}

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so if you're here, some things to note:

1. Don't use ADAL. Use MSAL. ADAL is v1 and does not work. Read here for examples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal
2. You should wrap your entire app inside the component you get from above. I will show how I did it below.
3. You must have already registered your app in Azure Active Directory, configured redirect URLs, and included API permissions.

**index.js**

```
import { AzureAD, MsalAuthProviderFactory, LoginType } from 'react-aad-msal';
import { msalConfig, authParams } from './msalConfig';

class Index extends Component {
  state = {
    userInfo: null,
  }

  userJustLoggedIn = (accInfo) => {
    this.setState({
      userInfo: accInfo
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <AzureAD
      provider={
        new MsalAuthProviderFactory(msalConfig, authParams, LoginType.Redirect)
      }
      forceLogin={true}
      accountInfoCallback={this.userJustLoggedIn}
        >
        <HashRouter>
          <App userInfo={this.state.userInfo}/>
        </HashRouter>
      </AzureAD>
    );
  }
}


  ReactDOM.render(
    <Index/>, document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

This might not be what your index looks like if you are using the most recent version of Create React App. I converted the Index into a component for a couple of reasons. First, the authentication loop for me was getting stuck 1 refresh short when redirecting. Second, so I could store the logged in user's info in state, update with setState (which forces another render), and then pass it as a prop to the rest of my app.

**msalConfig.js**

```
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    authority: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHORITY, //this should be "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>"
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, //just "<your-client-id>"
    redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT //"<url of your app or localhost port you dev on>"
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
};

export const authParams = {
//can be whatever api scopes you need here **as long as they are from the same API address**
  scopes: [
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/email',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/profile',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read'
  ],
  extraScopesToConsent: [
    //any non Microsoft Graph API scopes go here for this example
    'any extra strings of APIs to consent to'
  ]
}
```

Read above env files and variables here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

I have a .env.development and a .env.production with the proper redirect URLs for each.

---

After you have authenticated the user, you can access the API.

You need to acquire a token silently before each API call and use the token in the request. For me it looks like this:

```
const authProvider = new MsalAuthProviderFactory(msalConfig, authParams);
    console.log(authProvider)
    authProvider.getAuthProvider().UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(authParams)
    .then((res) => {
      axios({
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.accessToken
        },
        method: 'GET',
        url: "api address"
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //do stuff with response
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('axios fail: ' + error)
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('token fail: ' + error)
    })
```

I put this into a function and called during componentDidMount.

I will update if anything changes. I hope this helps someone.